# Spark AnalysisException: Table does not support batch scan

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm using Databricks Connects and I'm trying to run the next code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    
builder = (
        SparkSession.builder.appName('test')
    .config(
        "spark.sql.extensions",
        # "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension"
    )
    .config(
        "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
        "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
    )
    .config(
        # "spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode",
        "dynamic"
    )
    )

spark = (
            configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder)
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate()
        ) 

spark.sql("select * from mydatabase.mytable").show()
```

But I'm obtaining the next error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Table
> mydatabase.mytable does not support batch scan.;

This query works well in a Databricks Notebook on top of the same cluster. Any idea what could be the cause of this issue? I think it could be the Spark configuration

Comment: Is it a delta table? As you're using the `configure_spark_with_delta_pip`, are you making hive to read delta table?

Comment: I'm not using a delta table yet.

Comment: Whether I remove all the configurations I obtained another error:  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o74.showString

Comment: I suspect that your first error is due to the connector configuration between hive and delta table. For you second error that relate to `showString`, what's the error traceback?

Comment: Which configuration do you think could be the issue?